# Laravel whereDate() not working

Tags: laravel

I have used below query to get result with some codition in my controller

```
$events = Event::whereHas('topic', function ($q) {
               $q->where('delete_status', 0);
            })
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('delete_status', 0);
```

And in my view file i have used this variable thrice to check with Date like below

```
$events->where('type', '!=', 2)->whereDate('start_date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()
```

And

```
$events->where('type', 2)->whereDate('start_date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()
```

And

```
$events->whereDate('start_date', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()
```

Because i want to get the result based on past date or present date. If i use get in controller query i got error of **whereDate() does not exists**
So i have used get() method in view file.

I cannot get record from second and third query but I can only get record from 1st query in view file.

Any solution?

Comment: Why you used `->whereDate('start_date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()`. You can use `->whereDate('start_date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now());`

Comment: Tried `whereDate('start_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))` ?

Comment: @HirenGohel As i mentioned in my question if i use like that i got error of method whereDate() does not exist

Comment: yes but its not working @linktoahref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`$events`** is an collection which doesn't have `whereDate` method, what you might be looking for is the [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) to filter your collection in your views. Hence you could do so

```
$filtered_events = 
    $events->where('type', 2)
           ->filter(function ($item) {
                 return Carbon::parse($item->start_date)->gte(Carbon::today());
             });
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807605/5808894)

Comment: Working great.. Thank u so much